# Groff mom change table background color

Tags: groff

I build some tables with groff and the mom macro package. White is the default background color. Is it possible to change the background color and text color in the table? I would like to have red in the columns 5 and 6 as background color and in the columns 7 and 8 blue as background color. Are striped colors for the columns 1-4 possible?

```
.TS H
center, allbox, tab(,);
c c c c c c c c
c c c c c c c c
c c c n n n n n .
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any color in `groff`. Afaik it only does black (text) and white (background); apart from implemented images maybe.

Comment: This isn't true, `groff` can display colours. For example, see the [documentation for colours with the mom macros](https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/color.html#color-intro).